# devtools console: copy is not a function while on youtube

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, clipboard, google-chrome-console

I know that I can use `copy()` function on the console to add content to the clipboard.

When I am on any other page `copy('test')` works.

When I am on youtube I get:

> Uncaught TypeError: copy is not a function

How can I fix this. E.g. Is there a way to prevent a site from overriding specific functions using devtools?

Strangely on firefox `copy()` works on youtube, so could this be a chrome bug?

Comment: Run `copy` in console and you'll see it's a DOM element with id `copy`. Once you remove this element you can use the built-in API.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thank you for the feedback. indeed `document.querySelector('#copy').remove()` works. I wonder why does this happen? Are ids supposed to be accessible as variables? I try to access a differrent id by its name but I cannot. And why this does not work on firefox?

Comment: 1) see [Do DOM tree elements with ids become global variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3434278), 2) dunno, but google is known to serve different sites to non-chrome browsers.

Comment: Is there anyway to reinstate `copy`?

Answer (score 15):

The issue is that there is an element on that page with id="copy". If you type `copy` in the console, you should get a element printed out like this:

```
$ copy
<g id="copy"></g>
```

So, you'll have to remove that element before using the `copy` function:

```
document.querySelector('#copy').remove();
```

Running it in console again should show it's a function:

```
$ copy
ƒ copy() { [native code] }
```

Then use `copy()` as normal, e.g. `copy(myVariable)`