# Copy plugin for esbuild "is not a function"

Tags: typescript, esbuild

I'm working on an esbuild configuration and want to copy a file (`manifest.json`) to a specific folder when I build my project for testing purposes. I included the [copy plugin](https://nx-plugins.netlify.app/derived/esbuild.html#copy) into my `esbuild-config.mjs`

```
import esbuild from "esbuild";
import process from "process";
import builtins from 'builtin-modules'
import copy from 'esbuild-plugin-copy';

const prod = (process.argv[2] === 'production');
    
const baseConfig = {
    // ...
};

const testVaultPluginFolder = 'test-vault/.obsidian/plugins/obsidian-sample-plugin/';
const devConfig = {
    ...baseConfig,
    outfile: testVaultPluginFolder + 'main.js',
    plugins: [
        copy({  // <- This line causes the problem
            assets: [
                { from: ['manifest.json'], to: [testVaultPluginFolder] }
            ]
        })
    ]
};

const prodConfig = {
    ...baseConfig,
    outfile: 'main.js',
};

if (prod){
    esbuild.build(prodConfig).catch(() => process.exit(1));
} else {
    esbuild.build(devConfig).catch(() => process.exit(1));
}
```

I can even `Ctrl + Click` into the copy function in VS Code.

Then when I run it it tells me that copy is not a function:

```
$ npm run dev

> obsidian-sample-plugin@1.1.0 dev C:\Workspaces\RNSS-Sample\obsidian-sample-plugin
> node esbuild.config.mjs

file:///C:/Workspaces/.../obsidian-sample-plugin/esbuild.config.mjs:59
                copy({
                ^

TypeError: copy is not a function
    at file:///C:/Workspaces/.../obsidian-sample-plugin/esbuild.config.mjs:59:3
    at ModuleJob.run (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:170:25)
    at async Loader.import (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:178:24)
    at async Object.loadESM (internal/process/esm_loader.js:68:5)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! obsidian-sample-plugin@1.1.0 dev: `node esbuild.config.mjs`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
```

## Edit: Further research

I found this question where the copy (to clipboard) function produced the same error: [devtools console: copy is not a function while on youtube](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62212958/devtools-console-copy-is-not-a-function-while-on-youtube)

The problem was, that the DOM contained another element named copy that was not a function. Even though I'm not in a Browser here, I tried renaming the import.

```
import copyIsADamnFunction from 'esbuild-plugin-copy';

plugins: [
    copyIsADamnFunction({
        assets: [
            { from: ['manifest.json'], to: [testVaultPluginFolder] }
        ]
    })
]
```

Same result:

```
TypeError: copyIsADamnFunction is not a function
    at file:///C:/Workspaces/.../obsidian-sample-plugin/esbuild.config.mjs:59:3
```

When I remove the import I get

```
ReferenceError: copy is not defined
    at file:///C:/Workspaces/.../obsidian-sample-plugin/esbuild.config.mjs:58:11
```

So the import imports something. And VS Code tells me on mouse over that copy is a function with one optional parameter returning a `esbuild.Plugin`:

```
(alias) copy(options?: Partial<Options>): esbuild.Plugin
import copy
```

If I write `copy.` VS Code even offers me code completion like `apply`, `arguments`, `bind` and `call` which all belong to `Function.prototype`. How can `copy` not be a function?

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Comment: I posted it on Github as well. Apparently it really is a bug and a fix is comming.
https://github.com/LinbuduLab/nx-plugins/issues/66

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this was a bug in the plugin. It should be fixed in an actual version.

Beside this someone in [this](https://github.com/LinbuduLab/nx-plugins/issues/66#issuecomment-1067667913) Thread provided a workaroud which worked for me:

Instead of

```
import copy from 'esbuild-plugin-copy';
```

Use

```
import { copy } from "esbuild-plugin-copy";
```